# Nested routing: how to route inside a route?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm trying to create a nested route (I believe this is the term for it).

With one main route which supplies four entirely different pages (main-component.html is just the router outlet tags).

And inside the first route path, i want to have in one part of the page (center div) a second routing which will be navigated by arrow buttons (forward and backward). The content for this div is complex (including communication with a backend server) so a construction with *ngIf and different templates is not ideal).

Can this be done with two routes? And if so, how?

Comment: just add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` where needed, i.e in your "first route path" as you say. Those routes will then be children of your "first route path".

Comment: The documentation will help you: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-4-crisis-center-feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';

import { FirstComponent, 
         SecondComponent,
         ThirdComponent,
         FourthComponent
} from './app.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [        
    {
        path: 'first',
        component: FirstComponent,
        children:[
        {
         path : 'second',
         component: SecondComponent,
         children:[
           {
            path : 'fourth',
            component: FourthComponent
           },
           {
            path : 'third',
            component: ThirdComponent
           }
         ]
        }
       ]
     },
     {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/first',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
];
```

and components:

```
import { Component }          from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h3 class="title">Routing</h3>
    <hr />
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
}


@Component({
  template: `
    <h3 class="title">FirstComponent</h3>
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <hr />
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class FirstComponent {
}

@Component({
  template: `
    <h3 class="title">SecondComponent</h3>
    <nav>
      <a routerLink="second" routerLinkActive="active" >Second</a>
      <a routerLink="third" routerLinkActive="active" >Third</a>
    </nav>
    <hr />
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class SecondComponent {
}

@Component({
  template: `
    <h3 class="title">ThirdComponent</h3>
  `
})
export class ThirdComponent {
}

@Component({
  template: `
    <h3 class="title">FourthComponent</h3>
    <hr />
  `
})
export class FourthComponent {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create lazy loading. top root module with routing. following step by step Gide.

index.html file

```
<body>
   <app-root></app-root>
<body>
```

then create root.module.ts file and root-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RootComponent } from './root.component';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: './app/account/account.module#AccountModule',
    data: { preload: true }
  },
  {
    path: 'app',
    loadChildren: './app/app.module#AppModule',
    data: { preload: true }
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class RootRoutingModule { }

then create child account module and account routing. for following code
```

account-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AccountComponent } from './account.component';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AccountComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AccountRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: I'm unable to acces the 'child' routes, do I use <router-outlet></router-outlet> in both the AppRoot.html and AccountComponent.html (in this case, inside the center div)? And are there specific lines to include in the two module.ts files? And where should the '#AccountModule' refer to?